# Check if parameter contains column value in filter for data view web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, filter, xslt, data-view-web-part, filtermulivalue

I am trying to filter a dataview webpart using a parameter ($Users) which is a string of usernames delimited by a semicolon (domain\user1;domain\user2;domain\user3;domain\user4).

This string is being passed in as a query string in the URL. I want to check if this string contains the username in a column (@UserID). I've tried using the query:

```
[contains($Users, @UserID)]
```

This returns no results, even with just a single username and even when the parameter is not passed through as a query string and is instead just a default value.

Is the possible the way I am currently trying to do it? Should I split the string up and check each substring?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, there is nothing wrong in what you're doing..
but there could be multiple reasons of why this is happening.

you could check the values of each one of you variables (**Users** **UserID**).

and note that tha **contain** function is case sensitive.. so also check the spelling of the name.. 
if you can provide the results of the variables we may be able to help you more.